# HTML5 Mode in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Having problem while refreshing the page when **HTML5 Mode** is set. When navigating to `/path`, `it works` fine but when i refresh the page or directly type `localhost/path` `it does not work`.

## HTML5 Mode

Configuration:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/path', {
    templateUrl: 'path.html',
  });
$locationProvider
  .html5Mode(true);
```

You should set the base in HTML-file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
</html>
```

In this mode you can use links without the # in HTML files

```
<a href="/path">link</a>
```

Link in Browser:

```
http://www.example.com/base/path
```

Update on the server. At this moment, i am just using gulp module to connect.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('connect', function(){
  connect.server({
      root: './app',
      port: 8080
  })
})
```

Comment: HTML5 Mode uses PushState to change the URL without making a new server request.  however, refreshes and direct page loads will still make a server call, and need to be handled by the server.  Which server technology are you using, and is it configured with PushState support?

Comment: @Claies: We are using Java as backend.

Comment: ok, so what, Jetty? Jakarta Tomcat? 4J? some other web server?

Comment: @Claies: At this moment i am just using gulp connect module to host.... i have not yet integrated with actual back-end. updated my original post.

Comment: right, so node then.  well, this is easy with express since it supports rewrites, but I don't know about gulp-connect.   In essence, you need to take any request that comes in to your server and redirect it to your index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a middle-ware to solve the problem. 
Do an npm `install --save connect-history-api-fallback`. Add the following to your gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');
gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: './app',
    port: 8080,
    livereload: true,

    middleware: function(connect, opt) {
      return [ historyApiFallback ];
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Please take note of the changed API since v1.0.0. The middleware is no longer exported, but needs to be explicitly created.

refer: https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback/issues/10

Answer (score 2):

To make it work, you need to override all requests to non-static resources by your index.html...

For connect using connect-modrewrite module it would be, something like this:

```
var connectModRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');

connect.server({
  root: './app',
  port: 8080,
  middleware: function (connect) {
    return [
      connectModRewrite([
        '!\\.html|\\.js|\\.css|\\.ico|\\.png|\\.gif|\\.jpg|\\.jpeg|\\.swf.*$ /index.html [NC,L]'
      ]),
      connect.static('./app')
    ];
  }
});
```